# How to switch text direction to rtl & ltr in kate and kwrite

Tags: kde, kate, kwrite

How can I switch the text direction in kate and kwrite editors?

I have English & Persian layouts and want to read the Persian text as right to left but I can't seem to be able to switch the text direction.

Answer (score 0):

Try Right Ctrl+Right Shift for RTL and Left Ctrl+Left Shift for LTR.

https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=196287#c3

Comment: I've already tried that. Oddly it doesn't work for me!

Answer (score 0):

Unicode (UTF-8) has a special character called the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark. Try removing all occurrences of it from your document using the Replace function (Ctrl-R).

> Find: \x200F
>  Replace: (leave empty)
>  Mode: Escape sequences

While you are at it, try removing all eventual occurrences of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left-to-right_mark in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for Kwrite: Go to *View* and activate *Dynamic Word Wrap* or press <kbd>F10</kbd>. if you want to solve problem permanently go to settings->configure editor->appearance->General and activate `Dynamic Word Wrap`.